# How to Make Raycast Effect Named GameObject Only

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, collision

In my current(Unity 3.3 IOS)project I have a character walking across a bridge. If the character falls off 
the bridge he is to fall into a fiery river and explode. The problem is when he's on the bridge the Raycast reads the rigidbody on the bridge and he immediately explodes.  If I reposition him in the scene window to an open air position, the gravity causes him to fall into the river and explode as planned. I added the following line of code to designate only destroy if the raycast hits the "plane".  It doesn't work.

```c#
if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "plane");
```

The character does not get destroyed on the bridge or when he hits the plane/fiery river.

There are several bridges and buildings he will be walking into, so I only want him to be destroyed/explode if the raycast hits the plane.

**Can anyone tell me why my code isn't working or how to correct it?**

Here is my complete Raycast code.

```c#
var explosion : Transform;
var point : Vector3;
var explosionRotation : Quaternion;

function Update()
{
    var hit :RaycastHit;
    var dwn = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down);
    if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position,dwn,hit,3))           
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "plane")
        {
            point = hit.point;
            explosionRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal);
            Explode();
        }
}

function Explode()
{
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
    var instanExplosion = Instantiate(explosion, point, explosionRotation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your scene with the basic objects that are involved?

There are some problems that might occur.

- The bridge might be named "plane", too
- The ray is too long

Have you considered using layers? It sound like you use that ray only for falling/dying purpose for the character. You might want to add your plane to a separate layer and let the ray only check against that layer.